# Getting indices of most recent set of numbers in an array in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Let's say I have an array in Matlab:

```
x = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3]
```

I want the indices of the most recent set of consecutive `'1'`s. In this case, I want the answer:

```
answer = [16 17 18 19 20] % (which should correspond to the last sequence of 1's)
```

I need an automated way to do this in Matlab, that will work with any size arrays, always giving me the indices for the last set of consecutive 1s.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What have you tried? You need to show some effort on your part before anyone will want to put in any effort to help you.

Comment: I can't try anything, because I don't know where to start ;). I could setup a loop which will count down from the size of the array, find where the last 1 is, then keep going until it changes again?

Comment: Here's a starting point: find(diff(x)) will get you indices of the starts of new regions.  diff will output a vector one shorter than x, so be sure to adjust for that.  See what you can do from there

Comment: But your own comment is probably an even better starting point.

Comment: The matlab syntax for what you wrote in your comment is 'find(x==1,1,'last')' this is the index of the last 1. good luck from here!

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way of doing it:

```
I=find(diff([0, x==1, 0]),2,'last');
answer = I(1):I(2)-1;
```

`x==1` returns a logical vector that is equal to `1` everywhere `x` was equal to `1` and `0` otherwise.

```
>> x==1
ans =
 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

When you apply `diff` function on it you get another vector where the consecutive `1`s are removed and the last non-zero two elements relate to the original sequence of `1`s

```
>> diff(x==1)
 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 -1 0 0 0 0 0 0
```

However using this will fail when the first and last elements contain `1`, e.g, for `x=[0 0 1 1 1]` or `x=[1 1 1 0 0]`. So we add `0` to beginning and the end and `find` returns their indices

```
>> I = find(diff(x==1), 2, 'last')
I =
    16    21
```

Second argument of it says how many elements we want it to return and third argument says if they should be first or last elements. And now you can create the answer by

```
answer = I(1):I(2)-1;
```

Comment: Glad that it helped. If you find a correct answer you can mark it as an answer to help the community.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote [FEX:findseq](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28113-findseq) sometime ago to find starting/ending positions and length of consecutive streaks of values:

```
x = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3];

seq = findseq(x)
seq =
     1     1     3     3
     2     4     6     3
     3     7    10     4
     2    11    12     2
     3    13    15     3
     1    16    20     5
     2    21    24     4
     3    25    27     3
```

where:

- 1st col.: which value is repeated
- 2nd col.: starting position
- 3rd col.: ending position
- 4th col.: number of repeated elements

From there you can retrieve the positions of the last streak of 1s:

```
pos = find(seq(:,1) == 1,1,'last');
seq(pos,2):seq(pos,3)
ans =
    16    17    18    19    20
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little function that I created that will give you the start and end indices of whatever series that you're looking for:

```
function [first, last] = findLastSeries(aArray, num2Find)

    found = aArray == num2Find;
    ii = find(found == 1, 1, 'last');
    last = ii;
    while found(ii) ~= 0 && ii > 1
        ii = ii - 1;
    end

    if ii == 1 && found(ii) == 1
        first = ii;
    else
        first = ii + 1;
    end
end
```

Running the following script gives you this:

```
test = [1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 2 2 3 3 3 1 1 1 1 1 1 2 2 2 2 3 3 3];

[lFirst, lLast] = findLastSeries(test, 1);

lFirst
lLast

lFirst =

    16


lLast =

    21
```

If you want the full array of indices simply do the following:

```
range = lFirst:lLast

range =

    16    17    18    19    20    21
```